# How to get information from <select> and <option> tags

Tags: php, html, forms, html-select

Because I am not familiar with PHP, I am using GoDaddy's PHP Form Mailer. I have created a form on my website. Here is an example of what it looks like: 
                  
`<form action="_gdForm/webformmailer.asp" method="post" align="left">`
`<select>`
        `<option value="1">1</option>`
        `<option value="2">2</option>`
`</select>`
`<input type="submit" name="Submit">`

When I receive the email, I get all of the information from the `<input>` tags but nothing from the `<select>` tags. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Here is an example of the email that I will get:

FirstName: ~~~~
LastName: ~~~~
E-Mail: ~~~~ 
(I have a select tag after "E-Mail" that does not display)
Submit: Submit

I get no information whatsoever of my select tags.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: I've never used Godaddy's web mailer it's easier to write your own mail function, but I'm assuming that they require a way to select the inputs or selects value usually using an ID or an NAME and since your input has a name I'd say your select requires a name also.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a `name` attribute

```
<select name="myfield">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Your script probably parses all the fields by their name

Answer (score 1):

You have to name them, that's all, like you did with your input elements.

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input name="my-input">
  <select name="my-select">
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is because PHP only knows about form data with a name, it can't process anything else. In your PHP script the values are accessed as follows:

```
<?php

$_POST["my-input"];

$_POST["my-select"];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute is missing.

```
<select name="something">
```